# SQL Inner Join Combining Rows in Results - Too Few Results

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a report from four tables: Master, Details, Labor, Costs. Currently I have a working report pulling columns from Jobs, Details, and Costs. Shared key for all tables is JobNumber. I'm looking to get a sum of the costs and a sum of the hours for each job. Here is my code that works with three tables:

```
SELECT      
              JC_JobMaster.JobNumber, 
              JC_JobMaster.JobDescription1 AS Customer_Name, 
              JC_JobMaster.JobDescription2 AS Work,
              JC_JobSortCategories.SortCategory2 AS Work_Type, 
              JC_JobMaster.CustomerCode, 
              JC_JobMaster.ContractValue, 
              SUM(JC_JobBalancesCostDollars.CurrentPeriodAmount*-1) AS Gross_profit,
              JC_JobSortCategories.SortCategory1 AS City, 
              JC_JobSortCategories.SortCategory4 AS Salesman
FROM            
              JC_JobMaster INNER JOIN
              JC_JobSortCategories ON JC_JobMaster.JobNumber = JC_JobSortCategories.JobNumber INNER JOIN
              JC_JobBalancesCostDollars ON JC_JobMaster.JobNumber = JC_JobBalancesCostDollars.JobNumber 
WHERE   
              JC_JobMaster.JobNumber between '11566' and '13441' and
              JC_JobSortCategories.SortCategory5 = 'AWARDED' and
              JC_JobSortCategories.SortCategory2 = 'FPR' and 
              JC_JobSortCategories.SortCategory1 in ('1')
Group By    
              JC_JobMaster.JobNumber, 
              JC_JobMaster.JobDescription1,
              JC_JobMaster.JobDescription2, 
              JC_JobSortCategories.SortCategory2, 
              JC_JobMaster.CustomerCode, 
              JC_JobMaster.ContractValue, 
              JC_JobSortCategories.SortCategory1, 
              JC_JobSortCategories.SortCategory4
Order by 
              JC_JobMaster.JobNumber
```

Everything works fine - this query returns 45 rows with easily-verified data. However, adding in a fourth table using an inner join `INNER JOIN JC_JobCostDetailLabourHours ON JC_JobMaster.JobNumber = JC_JobCostDetailLabourHours.JobNumber` only returns 7 rows, and the summed column *Gross_profit* is incorrect. Using a LEFT JOIN as opposed to INNER JOIN gives me the proper 45 rows, but the summed column is still incorrect. The LabourHours and BalancesCostDollars tables have multiple entries for each job number that I'm wanting summed. What am I doing wrong with adding the fourth table, or did I just happen to get the right result by accident with the first summed column?

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Use a subquery where you distinct and aggregate. Then left join on that subquery

Comment: @GordonLinoff A left join gives me the proper amount of rows, but causes the first summed column to be incorrect.

Comment: @Gandalf What would joining the subquery look like? I've got the subquery written but I'm having a hard time joining it

Comment: Wow...  the scenario you described seems unlikely to me, unless I completely misunderstood.  Do you have some sample data and expected results?  I'd really like to see it and test for myself

Comment: Looking a little deeper at this, I am going to go out on a limb and say if you remove those three "SortCategory" conditions, your query is going to give you some extremely unexpected results.  I'm speculating, but if these are 1:many tables, then I think there is a deeper issue with your query

Comment: I wish I did @Hambone. I can take some screenshots but with this being a live database, I won't be able to provide any actual data.